# Variável externa recebe valor de um success

Tags: javascript, parse

Não estou conseguindo recuperar o valor da variável countEventChecks após o success. Como posso atribuir o valor de um retorno a outra variável?

```
for (var x = 0; x < eventosCkeckedPeloUser.length; x++) {
    if (eventosResponse[i].id == eventosCkeckedPeloUser[x].id) {
        confirmCheck = true;
        evento = {
            "id": eventosResponse[i].id,
            "img": eventosResponse[i].get("eve_imagem"),
            "checks": countChecks(eventosResponse[i]),
            "userCheck": confirmCheck
        }
        $scope.eventos.push(evento);
    } 
}

function countChecks(evento) {
    var relation = evento.relation("eve_users");
    var query = relation.query();
    query.count({
        success: function (res) {
            return res;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

```
function countChecks(evento, data) {
    var relation = evento.relation("eve_users");
    var query = relation.query();
    function data(response) {
        query.count({
            success: function (res) {
                data(res); 
            }
        });
    }
}

for (var x = 0; x < eventosCkeckedPeloUser.length; x++) {
    if (eventosResponse[i].id == eventosCkeckedPeloUser[x].id) {
        confirmCheck = true;
        evento = {
            "id": eventosResponse[i].id,
            "img": eventosResponse[i].get("eve_imagem"),
            "checks": countChecks(eventosResponse[i], function(res) {
                        return res;
                    }),
            "userCheck": confirmCheck
        }
        $scope.eventos.push(evento);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ja tentei desta forma mas está retornando undefined. Quando coloco console.log(res) dentro do success ele imprime o valor correto. Mas quando invoco a function countChecks(evento) de fora o retorno é undefined.

Comment: Você precisa de uma chamada sincrona, editei o script, verifique se funciona.

Comment: Acho que ainda não entendi. Editei o código pra voce ver onde to chamando a função.

Comment: Reeditei o código complementando com sua edição, verifique que irei explicar o que eu fiz dependendo do resultado

Comment: Bem, continua imprimindo undefined. Mas acredito que seja algo do Parse mesmo. Devo estar fazendo de forma errada alguma chamada. Vou estudar mais o Parse. Obrigado.